# Active tab password protection

Tags: javascript, passwords, local-storage

I have some **JS** for when the user leaves the web app tab and comes back it should prompt a password.

We have the same web app open in multiple tabs for different users and I want to:

- When a user changes tabs I want to prompt that a password is needed
- The screen should be white before the user enters the password

Sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't and I don't know why.

I tried clearing my cache, but it didn't appear to work either. Perhaps I should set the page timeout? I just don't want the page to time out because it may be executing processes.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
                // set the password that the user must enter
                const password = "12";

                // check if the user has already entered the correct password
                let authenticated = false;
                if (sessionStorage.getItem("authenticated") === password) {
                    authenticated = true;
                }

                // function to prompt the user to enter the password
                function promptPassword() {
                    const input = prompt("Please enter the password:");
                    if (input === password) {
                        authenticated = true;
                        sessionStorage.setItem("authenticated", password);
                        document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange);
                        showPage();
                      } else {
                        setTimeout(promptPassword, 1);
                      }
                    }

                // function to hide the page until the user enters the correct password
                function hidePage() {
                    document.body.style.display = "none";
                }

                // function to show the page after the user enters the correct password
                function showPage() {
                    document.body.style.display = "block";
                }

                // function to handle tab visibility changes (e.g. when the user switches tabs or minimizes the browser window)
                function handleVisibilityChange() {
                    if (document.hidden) {
                        authenticated = false;
                        sessionStorage.removeItem("authenticated");
                        hidePage();
                    } else {
                        if (!authenticated) {
                            promptPassword();
                            document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // initialize the page visibility system
                if (!authenticated) {
                    hidePage();
                    promptPassword();
                    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange);
                }
</script>
```

Comment: Your password prompt loop never lets the page fully load when the password is incorrect. Does it help if you change `else { promptPassword(); } ` to `else { setTimeout(promptPassword,1); } `

Comment: @AndrewParks Yes, that was a step in the right direction. Now, say for example I have three tabs open and going in-between them. It will work on time around for each tab then the white screen doesn't appear after that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this - although it won't run inside this web page because of the sandbox rules

```js
const password = '12'

function clearAuthentication() {
  sessionStorage.removeItem('password')
}

function checkAuthentication()  {
  const authenticated = (sessionStorage.getItem('password')===password)
  setBodyVisible(authenticated)
  if(!authenticated) setTimeout(promptPassword, 1)
}

function promptPassword() {
  sessionStorage.setItem("password", prompt("Please enter the password:"))
  checkAuthentication()
}

function setBodyVisible(v) {
  document.getElementById('content').style.visibility = v ? 'visible' : 'hidden'
  document.getElementById('container').style.backgroundColor = v ? 'lightgreen' : 'lightcoral'
}

window.addEventListener("visibilitychange", ()=>document.hidden ? clearAuthentication() : checkAuthentication())

checkAuthentication()
```

```css
#container {
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">secret document contents here</div>
</div>
```